# Voice recorder application not working

Tags: android, voice-recording

I created a voice recorder application I don't know why it crashes when I click record button.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "Audio_recorder_basic";
private MediaRecorder recorder = null;
private String path = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void startRec(View view){
    String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(status.equals("mounted")){
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Seba/audiorecordtest.3gp";

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(path);
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");

        }
        recorder.start();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SD not mounted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "SD not mounted");
    }


}
public void stopRec(View view){
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
}
```

The app only has 2 buttons with android:onClick="startRec" android:onClick="stopRec"

It also has 3 permissions (write and record audio).

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

path variable extracted from logcat `path  = /storage/emulated/0/Seba/audiorecordtest.3gp`

This is part of the message from Logcat:

```
    08-04 13:26:57.923    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
08-04 13:26:57.941    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
08-04 13:26:57.943    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:946)
08-04 13:26:57.943    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic.MainActivity.startRec(MainActivity.java:37)
08-04 13:26:57.943    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 13:26:57.943    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-04 13:26:57.944    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3829)
08-04 13:26:57.944    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4461)
08-04 13:26:57.944    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18526)
08-04 13:26:57.944    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-04 13:26:57.945    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-04 13:26:57.945    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-04 13:26:57.945    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-04 13:26:57.945    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 13:26:57.945    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-04 13:26:57.945    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-04 13:26:57.947    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
08-04 13:26:57.947    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 13:26:57.947    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
08-04 13:26:57.948    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
08-04 13:26:57.948    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
08-04 13:26:57.949    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
08-04 13:26:57.949    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ ... 15 more
08-04 13:26:57.949    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic E/Audio_recorder_basic﹕ create new file failed
08-04 13:26:57.949    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic E/Audio_recorder_basic﹕ /storage/emulated/0/Seba/audiorecordtest.3gp
08-04 13:26:57.977    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic V/MediaProfiles﹕ getInstance
08-04 13:26:57.977    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic V/MediaProfiles﹕ getLgeCamcorderCapParamByName: LgeCamcorderCap.audiozoomenable
08-04 13:26:57.977    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic E/MediaProfiles﹕ The mLgeCamcorderCap is not created, then return -1
08-04 13:26:57.977    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic D/MediaRecorder﹕ mAudioZoomEnable = -1
08-04 13:26:57.981    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Seba/audiorecordtest.3gp: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
08-04 13:26:57.984    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:458)
08-04 13:26:57.985    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
08-04 13:26:57.985    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
08-04 13:26:57.985    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
08-04 13:26:57.985    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:768)
08-04 13:26:57.985    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic.MainActivity.startRec(MainActivity.java:51)
08-04 13:26:57.985    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 13:26:57.986    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-04 13:26:57.986    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3829)
08-04 13:26:57.986    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4461)
08-04 13:26:57.986    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18526)
08-04 13:26:57.986    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-04 13:26:57.987    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-04 13:26:57.987    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-04 13:26:57.987    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-04 13:26:57.987    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 13:26:57.987    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-04 13:26:57.987    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-04 13:26:57.988    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
08-04 13:26:57.988    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 13:26:57.988    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
08-04 13:26:57.989    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
08-04 13:26:57.989    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
08-04 13:26:57.990    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
08-04 13:26:57.990    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/System.err﹕ ... 19 more
08-04 13:26:57.990    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic E/Audio_recorder_basic﹕ prepare() failed
08-04 13:26:57.997    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic E/MediaRecorder﹕ start called in an invalid state: 4
08-04 13:26:58.001    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-04 13:26:58.001    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d41d58)
08-04 13:26:58.004    4216-4216/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic, PID: 4216
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3834)
```

I use LG L50 for development.

Comment: add READ & WRITE external storage permission

Comment: try `path = status  + "/Seba/audiorecordtest.3gp";`

Comment: @Dhawal Sodha Parmar I did that a moment ago

Comment: @Kedarnath it crashes wiht W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mounted/Seba/audiorecordtest.3gp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar tried with adding Read external storage but crashed again with W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/external_SD/Seba/audiorecordtest.3gp: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: @Seba: check my answer

Comment: I think the path `/storage/external_SD/Seba/audiorecordtest.3gp` is invalid. You never should hardcode path to SD card.

Comment: @VladMatvienko how should I fix my code then?

Comment: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20open%20file%20from%20external%20storage&es_th=1

Comment: @VladMatvienko I am not using hardcode path anymore(answers below). But it still doesn't work.

Comment: show new stacktrace and update code than

Comment: added new code and logcat

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar,@VladMatvienko, This program actually works but I was searching for the file in the wrong directory. I was searching for the file inside SD card but the file was actually in the internal phone memory.

Comment: So what do I have to do to save the audiorecordtest.3gp to my SD card?

Answer (score 0):

You got an Java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/external_SD/Seba/audiorecordtest.3gp: open failed: ACCES (Permission denied)

I think you have to use

```
path = getFilesDir().getPath().concat("/storage/external_SD/Seba/audiorecordtest.3gp");
```

Comment: crashes with: System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.audiorecbas.audio_recorder_basic/files/storage/external_SD/Seba/audiorecordtest.3gp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

add below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

change below code

```
if(status.equals("mounted")){
        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/yourfolderName/audiorecordtest.3gp";
        File f = new File(path);
        if(!f.exists()){
            f.createNewFile();
        }

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(path);
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");

        }
        recorder.start();
    }
```

Comment: I added permissions and try and catch block for  `f.createNewFile();`. Also `"/yourfolderName/audiorecordtest.3gp"` is `"/Seba/audiorecordtest.3gp";`. The app crashess with `I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: The variable in my code:`path = /storage/emulated/0/Seba/audiorecordtest.3gp` but in my android's file explorer the path is `/storage/external_SD/Seba`

Comment: which android device you are using for development??

Comment: If I change to `path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Seba/"` my app doesn't crash but I cannot find the recording file in my android's file explorer and I do not get toast with "SD not mounted"